# Python tomar valor de una cadena despues de eliminar parte de ella

Tags: python, python-2.7

Lo que intento hacer es meter como valor de entrada una cadena donde tengo que eliminar la palabra "nombre:"y tomar el primer valor de la que sigue sin importar que exista espacio.
ejemplo:
entrada: nombre: pablo
salida-> p

si pudieran ayudarme trato de aprender python y no le entiendo muy bien a las cadenas

gracias.

```
#Este es el código con el que intente
com=0
letra=0
com= raw_input("Entrada:")

if 'nombre:' in com:
    print "encontrado"
    print com.strip("nombre:")
    letra=com.strip("nombre:")
    print letra[0]
else:
    print "no"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veamos:

```
com = 'nombre: pablo'
letra = com.replace('nombre:','').strip()[0])
```

- con `replace('nombre:','')` reemplazamos `nombre:` por una caracter vacio (eliminamos la palabra)
- con `strip()` quitamos los espacios en blanco si los hubiera
- Y con `[0]` hacemos un recorte del primer caracter de la palabra final

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!! es que aun no entiendo muy bien como manejar cadenas. enserio gracias !.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque lo aproximación difiere de la mostrada en la pregunta (manipulación directa de la propia cadena) otra forma mucho más flexible de hacer esto es mediante expresiones regulares. Por ejemplo:

```
import re

patt = re.compile(r"\bnombre\b:\s*(\w)")

cad = 'nombre: Pablo'
match = patt.search(cad)
if match:
    print("Primera letra del nombre: {}".format(match.group(1)))
else:
    print("Nombre no encontrado")
```

En este caso la expresión es `\bnombre\b:\s*(\w)`:

- **`\bnombre\b`** -> Busca la palabra `nombre`, gracias a `\b` (*word boundary*) no validará "pronombre", "renombre", "nombres", etc
- **`:\s*`** -> Dos puntos seguidos de cualquier número de espacios (o ninguno).
- **`(\w)`** -> Grupo que contendrá un solo carácter que pueda formar parte de una palabra.

Algunos ejemplos de salidas:

```
import re

PATT = re.compile(r"\bnombre\b:\s*(\w)")

def primera_letra_nombre(cadena):
    match = PATT.search(cadena)
    if match:
        return match.group(1)
```

> ```
> >>> cad = "nombre: Pablo"
> >>> primera_letra_nombre(cad)
> 'P'
> >>> cad = "nombre:      Pablo"
> >>> primera_letra_nombre(cad)
> 'P'
> >>> cad = "nombre:Pablo"
> >>> primera_letra_nombre(cad)
> 'P'
> >>> cad = "nombre Pablo"
> >>> primera_letra_nombre(cad)  # None
> >>> cad = "nombre: "
> >>> primera_letra_nombre(cad)  # None
> >>> cad = "Pablo"
> >>> primera_letra_nombre(cad)  # None
> >>> cad = "pronombre: él"
> >>> primera_letra_nombre(cad)  # None
> >>> cad = "appellido: Manrique, nombre: Pablo"
> >>> primera_letra_nombre(cad)
> 'P'
> ```

---

> Con `re.search` buscamos solo **la primera coincidencia** en cualquier parte de la cadena. Si sabemos que la cadena tiene siempre la subcadena "nombre:" (de tenerla) al inicio de la misma, entonces `re.match` es más eficiente. Si la cadena tuviera más de una coincidencia y queremos obtenerlas todas necesitamos usar `re.finditer`.